# jQuery v3.1.1 - window load

Tags: jquery

I had a pre loader which stoped working in jQuery v3.1.1.

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

I changed it to code below, but it does not work properly. The loader do not hide. Only after refreshing the page, it starts working.

```
$(window).on("load", function() { 
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");  
});
```

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/7juqbocd/) Please update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've tested the code on a page and it works fine. Please provide more code to find the problem.

Comment: Be sure to not wrap it in any other event as e.g document ready. See for more info: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194

Comment: I wrote it in $(function() {}); So when I move, it start working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your changed code seems to be correct.
I don't think it's because of your update to jQuery 3.1.1.

But it could be that you have an error in your other scripts on your website so that the script isn't triggered anymore. Do you have any javascript errors on your site?

Maybe try to change the position of your "load" function directly after the jquery implementation.

Comment: Issue is because OP is nesting event. See in comment, he is bounding load event from inside document ready jq pseudo event. But the question was missing this important info

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery load event was removed in jQuery 3.x. See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

You could do this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: OP is already using relevant alternative on jQuery: `$(window).on("load", handler);`. BTW, using `window.onload` property to set handler is bad, because using this way, you can only bound one event. Using `addEventListener()` DOM method would be more appropriate

Comment: @A.Wolff You are right of course ... However, he didn't seem to know that there is no more load event in jQuery 3.x.

Comment: I think he knew it because he posted alternative in question itself :) Otherwise, this is still good info for sure